# Load image url from css subfolder

Tags: css

My css file is available on the inner folder of css subfolder `/css/coverdesign/mycss.css`.

From that css I need to load background image url. Image is available on sub-folder `/images/`

I had used the following code.

```
background: url(../images/cover.jpg);
```

Guide me to load image by using proper url

Folder Structure:

```
/css/
    /coverdesign/
        - mycss.css
/images/
    - cover.jpg
```

Comment: So **css** and **images** are in the same folder?

Comment: @chipChocolate.py mycss.css is available in the sub-folder of css. And image is available in images folder

Answer (score 1):

you need to go up 2 levels

```
background: url(../../images/cover.jpg);
```

first level to coverdesign, then css, then down into images

Answer (score 1):

try absolute path

```
background: url(/images/cover.jpg);
```

or relative (go up two level)

```
background: url(../../images/cover.jpg);
```